# Use a widget in a statically-called method

Tags: widget, yii

Normally a widget is used by calling `CController::widget()` on an instance of `CController`, typically `$this` in a view.

But if I'm writing a static method, a helper, say, then I don't have access to an instance of `CController`. So how do I use a widget?

Let's say further that this helper method is invoked in the `eval()`’ed expression in a `CDataColumn`'s `value` property. That poor expression has almost no context at all. How should the helper use a widget?

---

### EDIT: Code example

As requested, a view example:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'attrName',
            'value' => '--USE WIDGET HERE--',
        ),
    )
));
```

Comment: yes, i need this one too, i need to get ->widget() to a string using static calling, have anyone found out how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer doesn't answer the question in general but in the specific case—how to access the controller and use a widget in the context of the evaluated expression of `CDataColumn::$value`—you can use this:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'attrName',
            'value' => function ($data, $row, $column) {
                $controller = $column->grid->owner;
                $controller->widget(/* ... etc ... */);
            }, 
        ),
   )
));
```

The trick was discovering that `CDataColumn::renderDataCellContent()` uses `CComponent::evaluateExpression()`, which injects the component instance into the callback as the last parameter. In this case that omponent is the `CDataColumn`, which references the controller as shown.

I don't like writing PHP expressions as string literals so I'm pleased to find this option.

A comment on http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#value-detail shows another way to us a widget in a column value that I haven't tried.

Comment: How do you do this on PHP < v5.3 without anonymous functions?

Comment: i have tried this but it does not work after you do a sort on cgridview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057927/cjuidatepicker-in-cgridview-as-form-field/26060757#26060757

Answer (score 3):

This one is working solution for calling widgets in static methods in Yii

```
Yii::app()->controller->widget('widget');
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way to call a widget out of controller because you shouldn't do so. It's all about MVC. Widgets are only needed and/or useful in views, and views are only accessed via controllers. That's the theory.

I guess you're approaching the problem mistakenly. A proper, MVC-friendly way to do what your're trying to do involves using renderPartial(). You know: you a have certain content and you want to decorate it (in your case you want to imbibe it inside a widget, right?) before displaying it to final user; so, from the view, you call renderPartial(). It will send your data to a file where it will properly decorated. renderPartial() returns the content properly formatted and now you can display it in the view.

Unfortunately, in your particular case, you're working with grid view (right?) and, at least from my point of view, it makes the things a bit harder. In order to decorate content for a CGridColumn-subclass element (like CDataColumn), you need to override the renderDataCellContent() method. Check it out here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#renderDataCellContent-detail

Comment: The example I gave **is** using the widget in a view. The CGridView is in the view. A data column's value property is an eval() expression http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#value-detail. There's nothing non-MVC about using a widget in the display of a table's data cell.

Comment: I never said that "using a widget in the display of a table's data cell" were non-MVC.