# CJuiDatePicker in CGridview as form field

Tags: php, yii, datepicker, cgridview, yii-chtml

I am displaying form elements in my CGridView and would like datepicker, but it complains

```
CDataColumn and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "widget".
```

I have modified `DATEIN` using the method described in [Use a widget in a statically-called method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898776/use-a-widget-in-a-statically-called-method) However i think it works partially as when i do a sort or the datepicker does not work. its working only on initial load.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*
    $("input[name*='DATEIN'] ").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).datepicker({'dateFormat':'<?=Yii::app()->params["localdate"]; ?>'});
    });
    */

    $("input[name*='datedone'] ").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).datepicker({'dateFormat':'<?=Yii::app()->params["localdate"]; ?>'});
    });
});
</script>

<?php 

$job = new Jobs();
$buttonPlus = CHtml::ajaxLink('Add New Line', $this->createUrl('addNewLine',array("id"=>$model->id)), array(
        'type' => 'POST',
        'data' => array('id' => $model->id),
        'success' => 'function(html){  $.fn.yiiGridView.update("jobs-grid"); $.fn.yiiGridView.update("detailsseismic-grid"); $.fn.yiiGridView.update("details3d-grid");  }'
));

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'jobs-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$job->searchbyproject($model->PROJID),      
        'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'function(id,options){
                            $("#jobs-grid").children("table").children("thead").children("tr").children("th").children("a").each(function(){        
                                $(this).click(function(){
                                    var x = getQueryParams(this.href);
                                    if($("#detailsgeoscan-grid").length)
                                        $.fn.yiiGridView.update("detailsgeoscan-grid",{data:"sort="+x.sort});
                                    else if($("#detailsseismic-grid").length)
                                        $.fn.yiiGridView.update("detailsseismic-grid",{data:"sort="+x.sort});
                                    else if($("#details3d-grid").length)
                                        $.fn.yiiGridView.update("details3d-grid",{data:"sort="+x.sort});
                                });

                            });

                            $("#jobs-grid").children("div").children("ul").children("li").children("a").each(function(){                
                                $(this).click(function(){       
                                    var x = getQueryParams(this.href);
                                    if($("#detailsgeoscan-grid").length)
                                        $.fn.yiiGridView.update("detailsgeoscan-grid",{data:"Detailsgeoscan_page="+x.Jobs_page});
                                    else if($("#detailsseismic-grid").length)
                                        $.fn.yiiGridView.update("detailsseismic-grid",{data:"Detailsseismic_page="+x.Jobs_page});
                                    else if($("#details3d-grid").length)
                                        $.fn.yiiGridView.update("details3d-grid",{data:"Details3d_page="+x.Jobs_page});
                                });

                            });
        /*
                            $("input[name*=\'DATEIN\'] ").each(function(){
                                jQuery(this).datepicker({"dateFormat":"'. Yii::app()->params["localdate"]. '"});
                            });
            */          
                            $("input[name*=\'datedone\'] ").each(function(){
                                jQuery(this).datepicker({"dateFormat":"'. Yii::app()->params["localdate"].'"});
                            });
                        }',
        'summaryText' => '',
        'columns'=>array(
                array(
                        'name'=>'JOBNO',
                        'value'=>'CHtml::activeHiddenField($data, "[$row]JOBNO")' ,
                        'type'=>'raw',
                        'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style' => 'display:none;'),
                        'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'display:none'),
                        'footer' => $buttonPlus,
                        'footerHtmlOptions'=> array('colspan' => '7'),
                ),
                array(
                        'name'=>'NAME',
                        'value'=>'CHtml::activeTextField($data, "[$row]NAME", array("size"=>25))' ,
                        'type'=>'raw',
                        'footerHtmlOptions'=> array('style' => 'display:none'),
                ),
                array(
                        'name'=>'SEQ',
                        'value'=>'CHtml::activeTextField($data, "[$row]SEQ", array("size"=>15))' ,
                        'type'=>'raw',
                        'footerHtmlOptions'=> array('style' => 'display:none'),
                ),
                array(
                        'name'=>'DATEIN',
                        //'value'=>'CHtml::activeTextField($data, "[$row]DATEIN", array("size"=>10))' ,
                        'value' => function ($data, $row, $column) {
                            $controller = $column->grid->owner;
                            echo $controller->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                                                                'model'=>$data,
                                                                'attribute'=>'DATEIN',
                                                                // additional javascript options for the date picker plugin
                                                                'htmlOptions'=>array(
                                                                        'class'=>'datefield',
                                                                        'id' => 'Jobs_'.$row.'_DATEIN',
                                                                ),
                                                                'options' => array(
                                                                        'dateFormat' => Yii::app()->params["localdate"],
                                                                )
                                                        ),true);
                        },
                        'type'=>'raw',
                        'footerHtmlOptions'=> array('style' => 'display:none'),
                ),
                array(
                        'header'=>"Process Complete <div id='checkboxgroup'> $processcompleteheader </div>",
                        'value'=>'$data->getcheckboxProcesses($row)',
                        'type'=>'raw',
                        'footerHtmlOptions'=> array('style' => 'display:none'),
                ),
                array(
                        'name'=>'DATEDONE',
                        'value'=>'CHtml::activeTextField((count($data->jobsprocesscomplete)>0) ? $data->jobsprocesscomplete(array("order"=>"datedone desc")) : new Jobsprocesscomplete , "[$row]datedone", array("size"=>10))' ,
                        'type'=>'raw',
                        'footerHtmlOptions'=> array('style' => 'display:none'),
                        'sortable' => false,
                ),
                array(                      
                        'name'=>'COMMENTS',
                        'value'=>'CHtml::activeTextField($data, "[$row]COMMENTS", array("style"=>"width:150px"))' ,
                        'type'=>'raw',
                        'footerHtmlOptions'=> array('style' => 'display:none'),
                ),
                array(
                        'header'=>'<a id="deletealljobs" title="Delete All Lines" onclick="deleteAllJob(\'1409099\')" href="#">X</a>',
                        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                        'template'=>'{delete}',
                        'footerHtmlOptions'=> array('style' => 'display:none'),
                ),

        ),
));
?>
```

I render it on from another view

```
$processcompleteheader = null;
    foreach ($processstages as $k => $v) {
        $processcompleteheader .= CHtml::Checkbox($k."_all",'',array("value"=>$k,"title"=>$v));
    }
    $lineListContent = "<div id='form_line_list'>
        <div style='display: block;
    left: 565px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;'> " .CHtml::hiddenField("PROJID",$model->PROJID) . CHtml::hiddenField("id",$model->id) . CHtml::activeFileField(new Fileupload,'jobs', array('onChange'=>'showLoadDialog();submit(this)'))."<a id=clearfile href=# onclick='clearfile()' />X</a></div>";
    $lineListContent .= $this->renderPartial("/jobs/_formJobsGridview",array("model"=>$model,"processcompleteheader"=>$processcompleteheader),true);
    $lineListContent .= "</div>";
```

Comment: Can you please add the code how you call it in CGridView?

Answer (score 0):

I think this question over here can help you out:

[Use a widget in a statically-called method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898776/use-a-widget-in-a-statically-called-method)

Basically this widget can be called by the controller, but in your code you are trying to call it by the gridview.

Comment: "However i think it works partially as when i do a sort or the datepicker does not work. its working only on initial load." This means your javascript in not loading. Can you share with us your render command please? Try setting it to render('viewfile', array(params), false, true);

Comment: Try `$this->renderPartial("/jobs/_formJobsGridview",array("model"=>$model,"processcompleteheader"=>$processcompleteheader), false,true);`